# How upload files with ActionScript asynchronously?

Tags: flash, file-upload

Note: I'm not aware with Flash/ActionScript at all.

I'm using Jquery [webcam plugin](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/) for capturing pictures from camera. This plugin provides ActionScript code that uploads captured pictures to server. It works fine except one thing - while file is being uploading my web page freezes.

Where can I read about async file upload with Flash or how should I change the following code to upload a file asynchronously?

```
public static function save(file:String):Boolean {


            if ("stream" == mode) {

            return true;

        } else if (null != buffer) {

            if ("callback" == mode) {

                for (var i = 0; i < 240; ++i) {

                    var row = "";
                    for (var j=0; j < 320; ++j) {
                        row+= buffer.getPixel(j, i);
                        row+= ";";
                    }
                    ExternalInterface.call("webcam.onSave", row);
                }

            } else if ("save" == mode) {

                if (file) {

                    var e = new JPGEncoder(quality);

                    var sal = {};
                    sal.sendAndLoad = XML.prototype.sendAndLoad;
                    sal.contentType = "image/jpeg";
                    sal.toString = function() {
                        return e.encode(JSCam.buffer);
                    }

                    var doc = new XML();
                    doc.onLoad = function(success) {
                        ExternalInterface.call("webcam.onSave", "done");
                    }

                    sal.sendAndLoad(file, doc);
/*
                    ExternalInterface.call('webcam.debug', "error", "No save mode compiled in.");
                    return false;
*/
                } else {
                    ExternalInterface.call('webcam.debug', "error", "No file name specified.");
                    return false;
                }

            } else {
                ExternalInterface.call('webcam.debug', "error", "Unsupported storage mode.");
            }

            buffer = null;
            return true;
        }
        return false;

}
```

Comment: File upload in ActionScript is asynchronous. Without having tested it, I would guess it is something other than the upload that is causing the freeze (like perhaps the loop over pixels, the getPixel() part). The code is in ActionScript 2, an old version of ActionScript. Stuff like jpg encoding images is a lot faster in the current version, ActionScript 3. If you can find another jQuery plugin for accessing the camera, a more recent one, using AS3, I guess that would be best.

Answer (score 0):

Pedro Correia shared an [actionscript class](http://www.pedrocorreia.net/mySnippets/actionscript/Actionscript-File-Upload) that implements asynchronous uploading. It is a little old (AS2, 2007), but might help.

Comment: It seems in that class user must select some files to upload, before uploading can be actually started. But I have data in the memory and do not have a local file actually